# Selenium for Edge in Build 18362 or higher

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I am having a difficult time with the webdriver for Edge. I know that the driver is installed via the command:

```
DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
```

But what is the next step after this? Here is my code in Java so far:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", "[I don't know the path of the install]");
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
WebDriver driverEdge = new EdgeDriver(options);
driverEdge.get("https://www.google.com/");
```

Comment: The next step would be to find where it's installed... But in general, if you can include the driver executables in your repository, then you'd *always* know where you could find the driver. Are you running your code locally or in a pipeline of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
 String windir = System.getenv("windir");
 String edgeDriverPath = windir + "\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";  
 System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgeDriverPath); 
 driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

This assumes 64-bit and I haven't actually tested it, so please let me know if it works.  For 32-bit I believe the directory will by "System32" instead of "SysWOW64".

Comment: Okay- I think I figured out what I was doing wrong. I guess since Windows 10 1903, the Edge Web Driver doesn't have to have a SystemsetProperty. So this is what I have now and am able to run without issues

Comment: WebDriver driverEdge = new EdgeDriver();
  driverEdge.get("https://google.com");

Comment: ohhh, I did not know that... System.setProperty will be for Java runtime, but are you saying that the line is not necessary?

Comment: Correct. I only had to use System.setProperty for Chrome, Firefox, and IE11.

Comment: thanks for letting me know... don't have a Win10 machine to test from at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

You could find the Microsoft Edge WebDriver from the following folders:

`C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_c52dd23839475f5b\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

`C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

`C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

`C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\wow64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_cf827c8a6da82156\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`

Then, refer to the following code to use Microsoft Edge WebDriver with Java:

```
package seleniumtest; 

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys; 
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
public class testsample {

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

         //String windir = System.getenv("windir");
         //String edgeDriverPath = windir + "\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";  

         //String edgeDriverPath = "C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\amd64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_c52dd23839475f5b\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
         //String edgeDriverPath = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";
         //String edgeDriverPath = "C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";

         String edgeDriverPath = "C:\\Windows\\WinSxS\\wow64_microsoft-webdriver-server-components_31bf3856ad364e35_10.0.18362.1_none_cf827c8a6da82156\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe";

         System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver", edgeDriverPath); 
         WebDriver driver = new EdgeDriver();

         //replace the URL of the web page here..
         driver.get("https://www.bing.com");
         //wait page load success.
         WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
         wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("sb_form_q")));

         //find the element from the web page.
         WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("sb_form_q"));
         //enter value and search
         element.sendKeys("web driver");
         element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);  
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [New in EdgeHTML 18](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide#whats-new-in-edgehtml-18)

EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).

---

As per the Microsoft blog [Enhancing automated testing in Microsoft Edge with new WebDriver capabilities, W3C protocol support, and automatic updates](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97):

> WebDriver needed to match the version of Microsoft Edge you’re testing against, which has historically required manually matching a standalone download of WebDriver to the appropriate version of Windows on your device.

So now WebDriver being a [Windows Feature on Demand (FoD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities), which ensures that it’s always **up to date automatically** and also enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

### Steps

- Enable Developer Mode which will install the appropriate version of WebDriver.

  ```
  Open Settings app > Go to Update & Security > For Developer and then select "Developer Mode".
  ```
- You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:

  - Search "Manage optional features" from Start, then select "Add a Feature", "WebDriver".
  - Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

    ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
    ```

---

### Conclusion

Once you install *MicrosoftWebDriver* with the **elevated command prompt** it will be updated automatically and you won't have to mention the *absolute path* of the *MicrosoftWebDriver* binary through `System.setProperty()` anymore.

---

### Reference

You can find a detailed discussion in:

- [Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly error using EdgeDriver and Microsoft Edge in Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59471353/microsoft-web-driver-has-stopped-working-a-problem-cause-the-program-to-stop-wo/59473613#59473613)

Comment: An important thing to note: make sure to **not** install the Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver package.  I had followed the steps you outlined (I found them on Microsoft's website) but I was still getting errors saying the connection was forcibly closed.  Remove the package solved the error.

Comment: @MarcLevesque Your comment should be pretty helpful to the community. Feel free to edit the answer and add this relevant information.