# Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly error using EdgeDriver and Microsoft Edge in Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

How do I run Microsoft Edge in Selenium. Each time I run a test, the Edge browser opens but does not load any URL. It then displays a small dialog box with the text:

```
Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program
```

I am using:

- Windows 10 OS 17763.914
- Selenium.WebDriver.MicrosoftDriver version 17.17134.0
- Selenium support Version 3.141.0
- Selenium Web-driver version 3.141.0 and
- Microsoft Edge Browser Version 18.17763.
- It's N Unit Framework with C#.

Code trial:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium.Edge;
driver = new EdgeDriver();
```

Comment: Try using chrome?

Comment: The issue occurs because you're using the Microsoft WebDriver version not matching the Microsoft Edge browser version. Microsoft WebDriver for Microsoft Edge version 18 is a Windows Feature on Demand. I'm in favor of DebanjanB's answer and you could try the steps in his solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error message...

```
Microsoft Web Driver has stopped working. A problem cause the program to stop working correctly. Please close the program
```

...implies that the *MicrosoftWebDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new **Browsing Context** i.e. *Microsoft Edge Browser* session.

---

As you are using **`Microsoft Edge Browser Version 18.17763`**, as per the documentation in [Enhancing automated testing in Microsoft Edge with new WebDriver capabilities, W3C protocol support, and automatic updates](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2018/06/14/webdriver-w3c-recommendation-feature-on-demand/#Rg8g2hRfjBQQVRXy.97), now MicrosoftWebDriver is a [Windows Feature on Demand (FoD)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/features-on-demand-v2--capabilities), which ensures that it’s always up to date automatically, and enables some new ways to get Microsoft WebDriver.

### Steps

- Enable Developer Mode which will install the appropriate version of WebDriver.

  ```
  Open Settings app > Go to Update & Security > For Developer and then select "Developer Mode".
  ```
- You can also install a standalone version of WebDriver in one of two ways:

  - Search "Manage optional features" from Start, then select "Add a Feature", "WebDriver".
  - Install via DISM by running the following command in an elevated command prompt:

    ```
    DISM.exe /Online /Add-Capability /CapabilityName:Microsoft.WebDriver~~~~0.0.1.0
    ```

**Note**: When installing *MicrosoftWebDriver* through the `DISM` command, by default the webdriver is installed within the following sub-directories:

- 64 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```
- 32 bit:

  ```
  C:\\Windows\\System32\\MicrosoftWebDriver.exe
  ```

---

### tl; dr

As per [Microsoft Edge Developer Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide):

> EdgeHTML 18 includes the following new and updated features shipped in the current release of the Microsoft Edge platform, as of the [Windows 10 October 2018 Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/whats-new/windows-10-build-17763) (10/2018, Build 17763). For changes in specific [Windows Insider](https://insider.windows.com/en-us/) Preview builds, see the [Microsoft Edge Changelog](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/changelog/) and [What's New in EdgeHTML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/whats-new).

Comment: Thank you @DebanjanB. I was able to install the "WebDriver" by following your installation steps and was able to run the Automation test through the Edge browser.